# Moq test on inherited class always returns null

Tags: c#, unit-testing, inheritance, moq, xunit

I am having a problem with setting up Unit Tests for a controller that implements a repository pattern. I want to check the return value of the controller. When setting up my Mock's for the Repository, the inherited IRepository methods always return `null`. I'm expecting to see the string "test" as defined in my `.ReturnsAsync("test")`

Repository

```
public interface IRepository
{
    Task<T> Get<T>(string storedProcedure, object template);

    Task<T> Get<T>(string sql, CommandType commandType, object template);
}

public interface ITARRepository : IRepository
{
    // other methods 
    ...
}
```

Controller

```
private readonly ITARRepository Repository;

public async Task<IActionResult> GetTARTrackerResponse(long id)
{
    try
    {
        var result = await Repository.Get<string>("spName", new { @Params = id });

        return Ok(result);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // logged
        ...

        return StatusCode((int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
    }
}
```

Test

```
[Fact]
public async Task Returns_OK_With_Tar_Tracker_Response()
{
    //arrange
    var mockRepo = new Mock<ITARRepository>();

    mockRepo
        .Setup(repo => repo.Get<string>("storedproc", new { test = 12345 }))
        .ReturnsAsync("test");

    var controller = new TARTrackerController(Logger, mockRepo.Object);

    //act
    var result = await controller.GetTARTrackerResponse(12345);
    var ObjectResult = result as ObjectResult;

    //assert
    Assert.IsType<OkObjectResult>(result);
    Assert.IsType<string>(ObjectResult.Value.GetType());
}
```

Comment: Can you please review your code and show mocks setup that matches the call in controller? It's very unclear what you expect to happen from code shown in the post...

Comment: Argument matcher in setup does not match what is actually used so mock wont behave as expected

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Argument matcher in setup does not match what is actually invoked in the subject under test, so the mock wont behave as expected when invoked while exercising the test.

The subject is invoking

```
var result = await Repository.Get<string>("spName", new { @Params = id });
```

While the mocked dependency expects

```
.Setup(repo => repo.Get<string>("storedproc", new { test = 12345 }))
```

Configure the mock to match exactly what is expected or loosen the expected match using `It.IsAny<T>()`

```
[Fact]
public async Task Returns_OK_With_Tar_Tracker_Response() {
    //arrange    
    string expected = "test";
    var mockRepo = new Mock<ITARRepository>();
    mockRepo
        .Setup(repo => repo.Get<string>(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<object>()))
        .ReturnsAsync(expected);

    var controller = new TARTrackerController(Logger, mockRepo.Object);

    //act
    var result = await controller.GetTARTrackerResponse(12345);    

    //assert
    OkObjectResult objectResult = Assert.IsType<OkObjectResult>(result);
    string actual = Assert.IsType<string>(objectResult.Value);
    Assert.Equal(expected, actual);
}
```

Comment: I'm new to Moq so thanks for the help. Would like to know if "loosening" the matching params is the recommended practice.

Comment: @dbarth in this case it would be difficult to match the anonymous objects so loosening  the match would be the recommended approach here.

Comment: @dbarth in other cases where the arguments could be easily matched then  do an explicit match.